# Packages for Ubuntu Core Snappy

Tags: package-management, ubuntu-core

How can I find out what packagges are available for Ubuntu Core? I've googled everything, but I can't seem to find a website like packages.ubuntu.com for Core.

Comment: https://uappexplorer.com/apps?type=snappy

Answer (score 7):

Right now the options are very limited. The available apps can be found by running:

```
snappy search '*'
```

Comment: Now it's: `snap find`

Answer (score 6):

You can find all the snaps available on the Canonical Public Store at-

https://uappexplorer.com/apps?type=snappy

The CLI `snappy search *` will only show you snaps that are compatible with your platform architecture!